# Best way to redirect on login page if user is not authenticated

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to create a Spring Boot project (version 2.7.4) to secure multiple applications with one security management. In my Spring Boot project I will add all the configuration for Spring Security needed for each applications. The generated jar will be imported in the POM of each applications to have the same management of the security for all (there will be only one database for connected users and rights management for all applications).

The aim is to have one login page (the same) for each application, so I would like to have it in my Spring Boot project and redirect to this page when the user is not authenticated (no JWT token in my case). After that, the JWT token is created and we should redirect to the home page of the application.

What is the best way to do it please? Having a login page in resources? Redirecting in a filter or in HttpSecurity configuration? Other?

How can we manage the JWT token created for each application to have it for each request when the login has been done (information: the front-end will be done with Angular for each application)?

Comment: It's a lengthy article but many of your concerns are addressed here: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

Answer (score 1):

You asking how to implement full flow from Angular to spring.

Here are some highlights:

1. You will need multiple security configurations where you can define your
   url matchers, because the sectiry jar is shared, the mathers should include
   the port of the specific application.
2. In order to maintain the stateless session, you need to send the JWT to the Angulr on login, you need to save JWT in angular and attach the JWT (to the header) when sending the request. Search for Angular HttpInterceptor.
3. As for the question about redirecting to login, you can do the following, when your angular request reach the server and the user is not logged in, spring security
   throw 403 error which mean you can catch this error in your Angular app and then
   you can redirect in Angular.

In your interceptor do the following:

```
.catch(error => {                 
      if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {           
            if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                console.error("Error Event");
            } else {                      
                switch (error.status) {                    
                    case 401:     
                        this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");                      
                        break;
                    case 403:     
                        this.router.navigateByUrl("/login");                      
                        break;
                }
            }
      }
})
```